# Loop to change Boolean to false after time?

Tags: java, loops, logic

This should be very simple but I can't seem to work it out.

I want to create a method which will return a boolean false value after a period of time once called.

I have tried for, while and switch statements but none have the desired affect.

REASON: I have an on touch event which which changes a boolean value to activate a game state. I want this value to change back to false after a period of time to avoid the user holding the the touch event to keep the game state indefinitely.

I have tried the below method in my game loop to change the value back false after a period of time. This will be called at the same time as the state activate method is called.

```
private void stateCounter() {
     int count = 100;
       for (int i =0; i < count ; i++) {
       stateBoolean = true;
       }
       stateBoolean = false;

}



private void stateCounter() {
     int count = 1;
       while (count < 100) {
       stateBoolean = true;
       count++;
       }
       stateBoolean = false;

}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: Clarify what you need, it'd be better to tell us why do you want do delay reading a variable .. If you do programming in an async system, and you want to delay reading a variable because you are waiting for something, then I think you should sync, with the process that affects that Boolean variable, before reading it

Comment: I have added a better description and a few loop ideas I had to get this working, I hope this clarifies a little better.

Comment: You should use a real timer. Your loop will execute these 100 increments in a very very short time, you'll not notice the change.

Comment: As Maroun said, you should use real timer. It is not because 100 increments will be executed in no time (you can do 10000 or 1000000), but it will give different delay depending on processor load and device. Real timer is independent in that way.

Comment: @MarounMaroun The problem is that my value doesn't change after increment, even if I made it 20,000 it still wouldn't change, that's why I wanted to get some clarity around as I assume I am making a mistake.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm not familiar with Real Timer and have never used it, is that suitable for the Android API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Handler.PostDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) Method to perform some tasks after an interval. For example

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // perform your tasks here
    }
},interval);
```

But One thing is not clear to me. do you want to change the counter when the touch is completed (i,e the finger is up). In that case you can use this

```
yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      // call the method now
    }
  }
}
```